# Unable to authenticate upload in CKAN

Tags: python, ckan

I have installed the latest version of CKAN 2.2 and I have setup the filestore using the documentation from this link  http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/filestore.html.

I got 'Unable to authenticate upload' error when I try to upload the data to my local installation of ckan.

I have installed pip install argparse and pip install pairtree.

I have set the ofs.impl and ofs.storage_dir values in config file.

ofs.storage_dir directory exist and it have the right permissions.

Apache error log not showing any error.

In the terminal It is showing an error:

```
Error - <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/ckan/default/pairtree_version0_1'
```

complete error log: http://pastebin.com/Y9rDWbbH

Comment: This seems to be a real write permission error. Although you said it has the right permissions, it seems not the case. Try `sudo su -c "touch /var/lib/ckan/default/pairtree_version0_1" <user>` for <user> is the user the process is running (double check).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UNIX permissions of your `/var/lib/ckan/default/` directory (or some of its contents) seems to be wrong. Try:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/lib/ckan/default
sudo chmod -R u+rwx /var/lib/ckan/default
```

Comment: This is not working for me. But I have tried this  'find /var/lib/ckan/default -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;'. Now the issue is fixed.